# How to get only Contacts with a StructuredAddress attached in Android?

Tags: android

By executing the following code i can parse all Android contact book items and attached postal address:

```
   Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
         String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
         Cursor addresses = mContext.getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
         while (addresses.moveToNext()) {
            String city = addresses.getString(addresses.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));    
            // other structured address fields.
         }
    }
```

I am not interested in address-less entries, does anybody knows if i can select only address book items that have a a structured address in the first query, so that i don't have to waste time parsing all of them ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. I have also been looking for quite some time to get it fast and correct. I came up with this:

```
private ArrayList<CustomAddressObject> getPostalAddresses(){
    Cursor postals = null;
    ArrayList<CustomAddressObject> results = null;
    try{

        postals = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int postFormattedNdx = postals.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS);
        int postTypeNdx = postals.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE);
        int postLabelNdx = postals.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.LABEL);
        int postNameNdx = postals.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if(postals.getCount() == 0){
            //No contacts with addresses
            return null;
        }
        results = new ArrayList<CustomAddressObject>();

        while (postals.moveToNext()) {
            CustomAddressObject address = new CustomAddressObject ();
            address.address = postals.getString(postFormattedNdx);
            address.contactName = postals.getString(postNameNdx);
            Log.d(TAG, "Contact name: "+address.contactName);
            if(address.address != null && address.contactName != null){
                switch (postals.getInt(postTypeNdx)) {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_CUSTOM:
                    address.label = postals.getString(postLabelNdx);
                    if(address.label == null){
                        address.label = getString(R.string.contacts_type_other);
                    }
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME:
                    address.label = getString(R.string.contacts_type_home);
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK:
                    address.label = getString(R.string.contacts_type_work);
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER:
                    address.label = getString(R.string.contacts_type_other);
                    break;
                default:
                    address.label = null;
                }
                if(!results.contains(address))
                    results.add(address);
            }else{
                //Some phones can store some information inside the postals that don't actually contain an address...
                Log.d(TAG, "Contact has no address with id  : "+contactId);
                Log.d(TAG, "Contact has no address with name: "+getContactName(contactId));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        if(postals != null && !postals.isClosed()){
            postals.close();
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```